# How can I search for number of .txt in my Folder

Tags: linux, shell

how can I search for the number of txt Files in my Folder.
i tried many things but nothing works.

ls -1 *txt
gave the list of txt's 
but i Need the number!

I also tried some combinations but that didnt work also.
ls-1 *txt | wc -1

hopefully you can help me 
thank you.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 1):

In your command, you do `wc -1` it's not correct.
you change letter **1** by **l** and it will work

i hope that help you

Answer (score 0):

some ways of doing this task:

recursively

1. `find . | grep -c '\.txt$'`
   1.1  `.` is for current working directory and all sub-direcotores
   2.1 `-c` is for counting
2. `find . -name \*.txt | wc -l`
   2.1 `-name` is for matching
   2.2 `-l` is for counting

non-recursively

1. `ls -1 *.txt | wc -l`
2. `perl -le '++$n for <*.txt>; END{ print $n }'`
   2.1 increase `$n` for each `*.txt` and print it at the END